# PHP Curl Image Upload

Tags: php, curl, image-uploading

How to achieve an image upload via cURL?

I was told to use curl_file_create but it's not working.

This is the array from post when I manually (using Chrome) upload a file and see the raw structure:

```
Array
(
    [image] => Array
        (
            [0] => 377529090726537.jpg
        )

    [thumbnail_digest] => Array
        (
            [0] => EMPTYDIGEST
        )

    [digest_present] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
        )

    [image_rotation] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
        )
)
```

Inside my cURL I tried:

```
$cfile = curl_file_create('IMG_33071.jpg','image/jpeg','test_name');
$post_data = array(
'image' => $cfile,
);
```

But after running the script, I receive this error:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class CURLFile could not be converted
>   to string in C:\Path\to\my\server\curl.php on line 144

The image is on the same folder from curl.php file.
My php version is 5.5.

I also tried this:

```
$cfile = curl_file_create('http://www.siteexample.com/path/to/my/file.jpg','image/jpeg','test_name');
```

But no success :(

My structure:

```
//These are the post data username and password
$login_data = 'email='.$email.'&password='.$password.'&entrar=Entrar';

//Create a curl object
$login = curl_init();

//Set the useragent
$agent = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
//$agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0';
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);

curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

//Set the URL
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_URL, $login_url );

//This is a POST query
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );

//Set the post data
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $login_data);

//We want the content after the query
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

//Follow Location redirects
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

/*
Set the cookie storing files
Cookie files are necessary since we are logging and session data needs to be saved
*/

curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');

//Execute the action to login
$LoginResult = curl_exec($login);
echo $LoginResult;



    //create array of data to be posted
$post_data = array(
'name' => 'Name',
'email' => $email,
'email_confirm' => $email,
'phone' => '9999999999',
'passwd' => $password,
'passwd_ver' => $password,
'create' => '',
);


//traverse array and prepare data for posting (key1=value1)
foreach ( $post_data as $key => $value) {
    $post_items[] = $key . '=' . $value;
}


//create the final string to be posted using implode()
$post_string = implode ('&', $post_items);

var_dump($post_string);

curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://urltocurl.com/verify');
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POST, false);
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
$answer = curl_exec($login);
echo $answer;


if (curl_error($login)) {
    echo curl_error($login);
}

//close the connection
curl_close($login);
```

Now take a look at the array at the beggining.

```
Array
    (
        [image] => Array
            (
                [0] => 377529090726537.jpg
            )
```

It is an array inside another one. How to achieve that? Maybe curl_file_create is working but it's sending the image to a wrong location of array.

Comment: see this:http://www.58bits.com/blog/2014/06/14/how-upload-file-using-php-curl

Comment: That's the place where I got some info. Even using its function, I get the same error =(

Comment: try with `test_name.jpg instead of test_name` may be extension is the issue.

Comment: see this:http://blog.derakkilgo.com/2009/06/07/send-a-file-via-post-with-curl-and-php/

Comment: Maybe I'm doind something wrong... The `[image]` is another array.... so it's an array inside another one. I'll update my post, take a look at the structure I'm using to send data.

Answer (score 2):

Look at my example it should work for you:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$data = array('name' => 'Foo', 'file' => '@/path/to/image.jpeg');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com/upload.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: No success... Maybe the structure is wrong? Please, take a look at the array structure in my question. I don't know if maybe that's why isn't working

Comment: `Catchable fatal error: Object of class CURLFile could not be converted to string in C:\Path\to\my\server\curl.php on line 144`

Comment: Updated. Take a look, please :)